# Errors while building app- Nextjs/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, next.js

I got the below errors while building my application. Not sure why this is happening. I wrote a fetch in a sperate function and my trying to call my fetch function (that is styled as a custom react hook) in my getStaticSite props but it is not letting me. How can I bypass this problem? I don't think I'd have this problem if I just wrote the fetch directly into the getStaticSite props, but for organizational reasons I prefer to write my fetches in functions.

The Error I get:

**./pages/SSG/paristimeisg.js
6:22  Error: React Hook "useFetchParisTimeISG" is called in function "getStaticProps" that is neither a React
function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks**

useFetchParisTimeISG code below

```
import React from "react";

export default async function useFetchParisTimeISG() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=Europe/Paris`
  );
  const currenttimeinparis = await response.json();

  return currenttimeinparis;
}
```

paristimeisg page code below.

```
import useFetchParisTimeISG from "../../hooks/SSR/ISR/useFetchParisTimeISG";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  let mytime = await useFetchParisTimeISG();

  return { props: { mytime }, revalidate: 60 };
}

export default function paristimeisg({ mytime }) {
  console.log("This is my time", mytime);
  return (
    <div>
      Hello
      <h2>{mytime.milliSeconds}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Extra question

I get the same error listed as the above for this page, despite not having any react hooks inside non react components(unless I am missing something?).

Error I get:

**./pages/SSG/timeforISG.js
5:16  Error: React Hook "useFetchParisTimeISG" is called in function "timeforISG" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks**

Page code

```
import React from "react";
import useFetchParisTimeISG from "../../hooks/SSR/ISR/useFetchParisTimeISG";

export default function timeforISG() {
  let mytime = useFetchParisTimeISG();
  return <div>{mytime}</div>;
}
```

useFetchParisTimeISG code is the same as above (top of page).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is a simple one - you are incorrectly trying to use a React Hook in a non-React component (getStaticProps, which is a NextJS function).

The solution is simple:

- Create a plain old JavaScript file that is not named like a Hook (e.g. parisTimeFetcher.js)
- Paste in your original code (with a function name change to avoid a possible React error over the "use" syntax, and remove the React import as it is just plain JavaScript):

```
export default async function fetchParisTimeISG() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=Europe/Paris`
  );
  const currenttimeinparis = await response.json();

  return currenttimeinparis;
}
```

- Now, import the function into your Next page, and use this function inside getStaticProps:

```
import { fetchParisTimeISG } from "../../fetchers/parisTimeFetcher";

export async function getStaticProps() {
  let mytime = await fetchParisTimeISG();

  return { props: { mytime }, revalidate: 60 };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helped me solve most of my problems. However, I have encountered something that is not explained by your explanation. I have added it to my initial question at the bottom. Let me know what you think @mojago.

Comment: Regarding your updated question: you have failed to name the React component properly this time. That's what the error message tells you. Rename "timeforISG" to "TimeForISG" and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Giving your naming that is prefixed with use, React assumes that you're trying to call a hook with its manageable state outside of a component (which it will not work) thats why it throws this error.
Hooks shouldn't be called inside a regular functions as mentionned in react official [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

You should change your naming and remove the use Prefix (You dont have to remove it from the the file name but its recommended)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).